# How to refresh Activity from AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, json, android-activity, android-alertdialog

In my program I am retrieving values from a json URL and then displaying them in a listView. now i want to delete some items from the list, so when I click an Item then the delete API calls in the doInBackground() of AsyncTask.. Now after completing the AsyncTask I want to reload the list so that the changes can b seen.

How can I relaod the list to see the changes..

My AsyncTask is a separate class.

this is my AsyncTask code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... DATA) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rqst_type = DATA[0];
    if(rqst_type.equals("del_top5"))
    {
        String url = DATA[1];
        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromUrl(url+memberId);
        Log.v(TAG_LOG, "del url: "+url+memberId);
        try
        {
            message = json.getString(TAG_DELSCS);
            Log.v(TAG_LOG, "msg "+TAG_DELSCS);
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.v(TAG_LOG, String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(rqst_type.equals("del_top5"))
    {
        if(message.equals("true"))
        {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Course Deleted");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Course Sucessfully Deleted");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        else if(message.equals("false"))
        {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Course Not Deleted");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.alert);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Unknown Erroe Occured");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.alert);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
    progress.dismiss();
}
```

The name of my Activity is `MyTop5.class` that I want to reload when I click the OK button of the AlertDialog..

this is the coading for my ListAdapter:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, LoadingScreen.top5List, R.layout.top5_list,
            new String[] { TAG_GLFCRSNAME, TAG_GLFCRSID, TAG_CRTDATE, TAG_FCLTY, TAG_HOLES },
            new int[] { R.id.top_golfname, R.id.top_courseid, R.id.top_createdate, R.id.top_fclty, R.id.top_holes });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

I usually pass in the Activity as a parameter to the AsyncTask and use that to call a public method on the activity when the work is done. It can be passed in through the constructor for example. I would then perform the changes needed on the list and then you have to remember to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter if you are using it as a ListView.

Comment: I also passed activity as a parameter along with the context to the AsyncTask. But I am now able to find the notifyDataSetChanged(). The name of my AsyncTask class is LoadingScreen, so the code i wrote was LoadingScreen.this.activity.notifyAll() and got a force close message. I am only getting notify() or notifyAll(). how can I get notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is a method on the adapter, not on the activity. Instead of passing the activity perhaps you can pass the adapter? The adapter has access to the list so then you can change that and when you are done you can to adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Be careful so that you do not change where your list is pointing though, that will remove it's connection from the adapter.

Comment: Can you please provide me some example code... as I am still not able to call the notifyDataSetChanged() in the same class where i have created the adapter for my ListView. I am getting the same notify() and notifyAll() when I tyr the following code: adapter.notify...().

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time to write something up but check this link out, it'll hopefully be good :)
http://www.dailygeek.de/using-asynctask-to-update-a-listactivity/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to make observer call on adapter.

Comment: I am now able to find the notifyDataSetChanged(). The name of my AsyncTask class is LoadingScreen, so the code i wrote was LoadingScreen.this.activity.notifyAll() and got a force close message. I am only getting notify() or notifyAll(). how can I get notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You must search that method on instance of your adapter class for ListView.